# Fatal Error Class not found - Namespace PHP

Tags: php, namespace

Ola estou usando os seguintes codigos php

```
<?php
namespace lab312\database;

class ScriptFactory

{


function __construct()
{

}

//outras funcionalidades


}
```

e

```
<?php
namespace  lab312\database\testes;
use lab312\database\ScriptFactory;

/* arquivo t.php*/
$script = new ScriptFactory();
```

no entanto quando chamo a classe Scriptfactory da o seguinte erro:

Fatal error: Class 'lab312\database\ScriptFactory' not found in t.php on line 17

alguma dica?

Comment: tá faltando o autoloader. PS: Se o downvoter puder se manifestar... é uma dúvida completamente válida.

Comment: O fato de estar "testes" no namespace do segundo arquivo não está fazendo com que o ScriptFactory seja procurado dentro dele? Tente o seguinte para ver se resolve: $script = new lab312\database\ScriptFactory();

Comment: Opa... falta um include/require do primeiro arquivo no segundo! Já fez isso?